# É errado dizer "vende-se casas"?

Tags: concordância, sujeito-indeterminado, voz-passiva

Eu sempre disse *vende-se casas* e frases do tipo, considerando que existe ali um sujeito indeterminado. Esse tipo de uso é reconhecido há mais de 100 anos, como analisado – e aceito – por [Said Ali](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Said_Ali_Ida) já [em 1908](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=BR4TAAAAYAAJ) (!). Até o Evanildo Bechara, um dos gramáticos brasileiros mais tradicionais, [reconhece esse uso](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&lpg=PT185&ots=E5n6iaJ7xE&pg=PT186#v=onepage&q=vende-se%20casas&f=false), embora o recrimine.

Mais recentemente, vimos uma ofensiva das gramáticas normativas contra esse uso, dizendo que sempre se deveria usar *vendem-se casas*, onde o "se" é interpretado como agente da passiva, tendo a frase o sentido de "casas são vendidas".

Afinal, onde está o erro em considerar que a frase tem sujeito indeterminado? Ela não faz mais sentido do que considerar que a frase está na voz passiva sintética?

Comment: Vendem-se casas é voz passiva, e "casas" é o agente da passiva. Formalmente, sim, é errado, e pode resultar em perda de pontos em uma avaliação. Ms a língua é feita pelas pessoas que a falam e, como tal, muda. Hoje já é aceitável usar "Vende-se casas" no português (Brasileiro) coloquial, e a tendência é que deixe de ser formalmente exigido obedecer ao agente da passiva no futuro.

Comment: Mas é justamente isso que eu estou questionando. Pode-se interpretar como voz passiva ou não. Aliás, a minha frase anterior tem sujeito indeterminado ou está na voz passiva? Para mim ambas as interpretações são possíveis e válidas, não entendo por que os gramáticos cismam em querer vetar uma delas.

Comment: Aí é que está o problema. Temos academias de letras e gramáticos. Enquanto eles decidirem que uma das interpretações tem precedência, essa é a norma culta. São as desvantagens de centralizar decisões que padronizem a língua. O ideal é que lingüistas cobrem um relaxamento disso, a meu ver.

Comment: Concordo, @FernandoCordeiro. No fundo eu perguntei pra provocar um comentário como esse seu :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As três obras que consultei descrevem todas usos do clítico impessoal com verbos transitivos e não os apontam como desvio, ainda que possam indicar a existência opiniões em sentido distinto (e com a ressalva que só talvez a primeira se poderá considerar normativa).

João Andrade Peres e Telmo Móia em *Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa* (p. 234, mantida a ortografia):

> O clítico *se* impessoal é uma expressão que indica a existência de um sujeito indeterminado numa frase. Observem-se os seguintes três exemplos:
>       (814) Naquela festa, cantou-se a noite inteira.
>       (815) Vive-se bem países de clima mediterrânico.
>       (816) Ouve-se ruídos durante a noite.
>   Este clítico impessoal acompanha sempre formas verbais singulares. [...] Distingue-se [...] do clítico apassivante, que pode ser combinado [...] com formas verbais singulares e plurais. Distingue-se ainda do clítico apassivante no que respeita ao tipo de verbos com que se pode combinar. Com efeito, pode surgir tanto em frases com verbos intransitivos — do tipo de (814) e (815), em que temos os verbos *cantar* e *viver*, respectivamente — como em frases com verbos transitivos — do tipo de (816), em que temos o verbo *ouvir*. Já o clítico *se* passivo só é compatível, como vimos, com verbos transitivos.

E a ressalva (negrito meu):

> A propósito desta questão, importa notar que alguns puristas apenas admitem construções em que o clítico *se* impessoal se combina com verbos intransitivos, rejeitando, pois, frases em que o verbo é transitivo e tem um segundo argumento não preposicionado com que não concorda, como acontece nas seguintes frases:
>       (817) Ouve-se vários ruídos durante toda a noite.
>       (818) Recitou-se verbos de Pessoa.
>       (818) Vende-se casas.
>   Como a alternativa a estas estruturas, propõem construções passivas de clítico, em que o verbo surge na forma plural. [...]
>   Na nossa opinião, ambas as construções são aceitáveis, embora admitamos que se possa preferir uma ou outra por razões estilísticas. A nossa posição resulta da consideração de dois factores: por um lado, **a aceitação generalizada por parte dos falantes** que o uso clítico impessoal com verbos transitivos parece ter; por outro lado, o facto de **não julgarmos haver razões — estruturais ou semânticas — para aceitar a construção com clítico impessoal nuns casos e rejeitá-la noutros**.

E desvalorizam o facto de isto gerar frases estruturalmente ambíguas (p. 235):

> No que respeita aos casos em que a forma verbal é transitiva e singular, pode verificar-se uma de duas situações: ou o segundo argumento do verbo é plural — caso em que não concorda com o verbo —, e estamos perante uma construção impessoal [...], ou o segundo argumento é singular, [...] — *comprou-se um livro encadernado*. Admitimos duas possibilidades de análise estrutural deste tipo de frases — como construções passivas (em que o argumento interno — neste caso, *um livro encadernado* — é sujeito) e como construções impessoais (em que temos um sujeito indeterminado e o argumento interno é complemento direto). Pode-se, pois, dizer que [tais] frases [...] são estrutalmente ambíguas. Trata-se, no entanto, de uma ambiguidade estritamente sintática, que não tem consequências ao nível semântico, já que a informação veiculada é a mesma nas duas construções. Na frase [atrás], por exemplo, temos a mesma relação — denotada pelo verbo *comprar* — entre um Agente em ambos os casos indeterminado e um mesmo Paciente — representado por *um livro encadernado*.

Quanto à *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, esta vai na mesma linha. No capítulo 13 ("Orações Ativas, Passivas, Incoativas e Médias"), na página 446:

> [As orações ativas de *se* impessoal podem] conter um verbo transitivo (cf. *nesta praia, vende-se apartamentos*, parafraseável por ‘nesta praia, {as pessoas/há pessoas que} vendem apartamentos’ ou ‘nesta praia, alguém vende apartamentos’) [...].

Há pequena nota de rodapé depois do exemplo “Descobriu-se os genes no séc. XX”:

> Exemplos deste tipo, com um verbo transitivo no singular e sintagma nominal plural, são frequentemente estigmatizados na norma padrão.

No capítulo 11, há alguma especulação em relação ao motivo da rejeição por alguns da construção impessoal (p. 392):

> A construção de *se* impessoal ilustrada em (69d) [“*Comeu-se* morangos à sobremesa”], com o verbo no singular e com um complemento direto plural, é por vezes estigmatizada, plausivelmente em virtude de estar em concorrência com a construção passiva pronominal *comeram-se morangos à sobremesa*, na qual o argumento interno se realiza como sujeito gramatical, concordando com o verbo. Outro par de exemplos do mesmo tipo, frequentemente citado na literatura gramatical,  *vende-se casas* vs. *vendem-se casas*. Esse estigma deve-se talvez ao facto de os verbos verdadeiramente impessoais ­— que não selecionam um sujeito, como *haver* ­— serem raros e relativamente marcados em português [...]. Em (69d) e similares, os falantes porventura reagem mal à presença de um sintagma nominal que poderia funionar como sujeito mas não funciona — o argumento interno SN —, preferindo a construção alternativa em que esse argumento assume efetivamente a função de sujeito — ou seja, a construção passiva pronominal.

Por fim, Mira Mateus et al, em *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* (6ª ed., p. 836, referências omitidas):

> Em frases como as seguintes, o sujeito frásico, que denota uma entidade arbitrária, é assinalado pelo clítico *se*. Estamos pertante o que alguns autores designaram por clítico sujeito impessoal ou indeterminado e outros *se-nominativo*.
>   (40) (a) A grande questão está naquilo em que *se* acredita.
>           (b) *Aluga-se* casas.
>           (c) *Trabalha-se* demais.
>   O sujeito associado a este clítico é interpretado como indefinido e não-específico, sendo parafraseável por expressões nominais como *alguém*.

Comment: Excelente! Só não percebi uma coisa: na primeira fonte citada, qual é a diferença entre os exemplos (816) e (817)? Não vejo como o quantificador possa interferir na transitividade do verbo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não há nenhuma. Simplesmente os autores decidiram não reciclar os exemplos. Estão a fazer comentários distintos em relação aos dois grupos de exemplos.

Answer (score 10):

Para mim, a gramática tradicional é neste ponto incoerente e absurda. Aqui está o que eu apurei.

Na gramática tradicional, a voz passiva sintética (**VPS**) funciona somente com verbos transitivos diretos, tal como a analítica, e do seguinte modo a partir da voz ativa (**VA**):

> (a1 VA) Nós bebemos vinho; (a2 VPS) bebe-se vinho.
>
> (b1 VA) Nós bebemos uns copos de vinho; (a2 VPS) bebem-se uns copos de vinho.

Ou seja, o objeto direto da VA, *vinho, uns copos de vinho*, passa a sujeito oficial da VPS, e o ***se*** de algum modo 'apassiva' o verbo. O verbo está na terceira pessoa e concorda em número com o 'sujeito oficial'.

Depois existe a voz ativa com o pronome indefinido ***se*** ou índice de indeterminação do sujeito ***se*** (**VASI** para voz ativa com sujeito indeterminado). Na gramática tradicional, [Isto funciona com verbos intransitivos e verbos transitivos indiretos (**Vti**), mas não com verbos transitivos diretos](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint8.php). O verbo fica sempre na terceira pessoa do singular.

Portanto, de acordo com a gramática tradicional, ***vende-se casas*** está errado porque:

1. Não é VPS porque o verbo não concorda em número com o sujeito oficial, *casas*.
2. Não é VASI, porque a VASI não admite verbos transitivos diretos como *vender*.

Ora aí está! Agora a gramática tradicional admite umas coisas curiosas. As frases seguintes são exemplos legítimos de VASI:

> (c1 VA) Vamos à festa; (c2 VASI) vai-se à festa. (Verbo intransitivo.)
>
> (d1) VA) Gostamos de vinho; (d2 VASI) gosta-se de vinho. (Vti)
>
> (e1 VA) Gostamos de uns copos de vinho; (e2 VASI) gosta-se de uns copos de vinho. (Vti)

Portanto na frase seguinte,

> (d2) Gosta-se de vinho, (a2) bebe-se vinho,

de acordo com a gramática tradicional, *vinho* é objeto indireto de (d2) e sujeito de (a2)! Porque *gostar* é transitivo indireto, e *beber* é transitivo direto! E vejamo agora a frase seguinte:

> Foi um belo dia: (f1) foi-se à praia; (f2) deu-se um mergulho; (f3) comeu-se uma sardinhada; (f4) falou-se das novidades.

De acordo com a gramática tradicional, (f1) é VASI, (f2) é VPS com sujeito *mergulho*, (f3) é VPS com sujeito *sardinhada*, e (f4) é novamente VASI.

Eh pá, eu acho que qualquer pessoa normal olha para aquela frase e diz que o sujeito é o mesmo em todas as orações (f1) a (f4), que é um sujeito formalmente indeterminado, mas que é um grupo de pessoas que provavelmente inclui o locutor: eles foram à praia e fizeram aquelas coisas todas. A recusa em aceitar que (f2) e (f3) sejam VASI, porque os verbos são transitivos diretos, parece-me resultar unicamente de não se querer que haja frases que possam ser VPS e VASI ao mesmo tempo. E é por isso, caro bfavaretto, que estás a violar a boa gramática quando dizes *vende-se casas!*

Mas... mas... mas encontrei estas páginas todas no cibedúvidas que com mais ou menos entusiasmo aceitam construções a análogas a *vende-se casas*, isto é, VASI com verbos transitivos diretos

1. [Aceita sem reservas ***fala-se línguas estrageiras***.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vende-se-ou-vendem-se/224)
2. [Aceita sem reservas ***vende-se maçãs***.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-as-funcoes-do-se/13963)
3. [Aceita ***vende-se parafusos***](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vende-se-ou-vendem-se-ii/652), mas diz que há gramáticos do bons que o "repudiam fortemente," e que há outras maneiras de dizer.
4. [Diz que a forma correta é ***veem-se as nuvens*** e não ***vê-se as nuvens***](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/nao-se-veem-nuvens-se-apassivante-e-concordancia/33580) , mas lá diz numa nota de rodapé com letras minúsculas que há certas gramáticas que aceitam as duas.

Nota: lembrei-me de responder a esta questão depois de ter andado a investigar estas coisas para [estoutra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-voz-passiva-passive-voice-construction).

Comment: Gostei, você mostrou bem certas incoerências das gramáticas normativas.

Answer (score 6):

Pesquisei no google a mesma questão e acabei por [achar uma parecida se não igual](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vende-se-ou-vendem-se/224), segundo a resposta é correto dizer `vendem-se` ou `vende-se`, eis a explicação:

**Se - palavra apassivante ou apassivadora e pronome indefinido;** este, como indeterminante do sujeito.

1. É palavra apassivante, quando, ligada ao verbo, o torna de valor passivo:

   - Alugam-se quartos.
     É o mesmo que «Quartos são alugados», embora não digamos assim. Mas uma coisa é ter sentido, **valor** passivo; outra é podermos dizer «Quartos são alugados», ou «São alugados quartos», que são frases que, assim isoladas, não empregamos. Aqui, **quartos** é o sujeito.
2. A outra função é a de pronome indefinido. Chama-se assim, porque **indefine** o sujeito, **indetermina-o**:

   - Aqui está-**se** bem. Na África, morre-**se** de fome.
     Estas frases não as podemos transformar em «Aqui **é estado** bem», «Na África é morrido de fome».

Seguindo este raciocínio, são corretas estas duas construções:

1. «Falam-se línguas estrangeiras.»
2. «Fala-se línguas estrangeiras.»

Na **primeira** frase, temos a voz passiva, à semelhança da frase «Alugam-se quartos». O **se** é palavra apassivante (e não pronome).

Na **segunda** frase, temos a indeterminação do sujeito, como em «Aqui está-**se** bem. Na África morre-**se**», operada pela palavra apassivante ou apassivadora **se** Empregamos esta construção, quando não sabemos qual é o sujeito ou, sabendo-o, não o queremos determinar. Neste caso, o verbo fica na 3.ª pessoa do singular.

Comment: Em Portugal é mais comum dizer "alugam-se quartos" ou "aluga-se quartos"?

Comment: Eu arriscaria a dizer **alugam-se quartos** em vez de **aluga-se quartos**, isto porque **alugam-se** poderia ser interpretado como plural enquanto que o **aluga-se** seria singular. Porém, isto não é levado à **regra** até porque normalmente as pessoas numa conversa conseguem entender, levando a que isto se torne hábito e passe de gerações a gerações, ficando assim _entranhado_ nas raízes da língua.

Para terminar, fiz uma pequena pesquisa em um site de [classificados](http://olx.pt/ads/q-aluga-se-quartos/) onde pesquisei por **aluga-se quartos**, vê por ti mesmo, espero que isto ajude!

Comment: Em _está-se_ o pronome _se_ não indicada _indeterminação_, mas sim que o sujeito a que se refere está implícito. Neste sentido, _estar_ é um verbo reflexivo.

Comment: Estar nesse contexto, reflexivo? Eu não digo _estou-me bem_. Quando muito, estou-me nas tintas.

Comment: @RebeloX Fui ver os classificados, mas desisti à terceira página. O pessoal só tem uma casa ou quarto para arrendar, logo não dá para testar o *arrenda-se/vende-se/aluga-se casas*.

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta Curta e Objetiva** - (Norma culta da língua)

**1. Se a frase admite a voz passiva, o verbo deve concordar em número com o objeto da voz ativa. (sujeito da passiva)**

- Alugam-se casas ---> voz passiva ---> Casas são alugadas.
- Consertam-se fechaduras ---->  voz passiva ---> Fechaduras são consertadas.

**2. Se a frase não admite a voz passiva, geralmente porque o verbo é transitivo indireto, não é o caso de se pensar em concordância.**

- Conta-se **com** os amigos.  (uma dica: o verbo não vai para o plural por causa da **preposição**, pois verbos transitivos indiretos não admitem a voz passiva)
- Precisa-se **de** empregados - idem

Comment: Pronto, @Centaurus. É isso! Mas, recentemente, fiquei confuso com uma locução verbal porque a análise não ficou tão intuitiva. https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8991/11522

Answer (score 1):

Penso que o raciocínio do gramático tradicional é o seguinte:

> Na Praia do Palmito, vendem casas pela hora da morte.

É um caso em que o sujeito é evidentemente indeterminado. Alguém vende casas pela hora da morte. Quem? O ouvinte que descubra. E, portanto, a construção pronominal deve conter um pronome indeterminativo:

> Na Praia do Palmito, vende-se casas pela hora da morte.

Mas vejamos o caso seguinte:

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, vende-se casas a preços ridículos.

Ou

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, vendem-se casas a preços ridículos.

Existem aqui dois possíveis significados:

- Primeiro, pode ser que se esteja dizendo que a imobiliária vende casas por preços ridículos.
- Segundo, pode ser que se esteja dizendo que clientes da imobiliária vão lá e vendem suas casas por preços ridículos.

E neste caso, somente a segunda acepção é indeterminada; a primeira tem um pronome oculto bem determinado, "nós":

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, vendemos casas a preços ridículos.

Ora, como não há indeterminação aqui, o pronome não pode ser indeterminativo. Ele tem de ser apassivador, por que a construção é passiva:

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, casas são vendidas (por nós) a preços ridículos.

Já a segunda acepção é obviamente indeterminada:

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, casas são vendidas (por alguém, não por nós) a preços ridículos.

E aí a lógica é que a primeira acepção, sendo uma construção passiva, tem o objeto da frase na voz ativa por sujeito. As casas é que são ***vendidas***, logo, ***vendem-se*** as casas.

---

O problema é que essa é uma distinção que os falantes - e os "escreventes" - não fazem mais. Para o falante médio do português, e mesmo para uma boa parte dos mais sofisticados, "as casas" não é sujeito dessas construções em nenhum caso; é sempre objeto. E o verbo não concorda com o objeto.

---

Na dúvida, eu usaria sempre as construções ativas. São mais elegantes e não deixam margem a ambiguidades.

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, vendemos casas a preços ridículos.

Se você acreditar, vá lá, para comprar uma casa barata.

> Aqui na Imobiliária Acredite Se Quiser, vendem casas a preços ridículos.

Vá lá, se você quiser vender sua casa por muito menos do que ela vale...

Comment: Concordo com seu raciocínio, mas tem mais uma coisa: vários "gramáticos" (de botequim) costumam reclamar de placas onde se lê (hehe) apenas "Vende-se casas". Nesse caso o contexto é bem vago.

Comment: Bem, entendo que existe a linguagem formal, que deve procurar seguir as regras mais difundidas pelos gramáticos. Já que muitas vezes os próprios gramáticos discordam em alguns pontos. E existe a linguagem informal, que as pessoas falam no dia a dia. Em algum momento, caso o uso passe a ser dominante e haja consenso entre os gramáticos, elementos da linguagem informal podem virar regras gramaticais.