# Havia ou haviam?

Tags: concordância-verbal, número-gramatical

Porque a frase: 'Havia muitos problemas' está correta?

Não seria correto utilizar o verbo haver em concordância, no caso: 'Haviam muitos problemas'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Haviam muitos problemas* não está correto em português padrão porque, no sentido de *existir*, *haver* é impessoal transitivo; *muitos problemas* é portanto um complemento direto e não um sujeito de *haver* e não há concordância<sup>1</sup>.

Uma indicação de que *muitos problemas* é complemento direto é o facto de que *muitos problemas* pode ser substituído por um pronome clítico acusativo. Compara as seguintes frases:

> Havia muitos problemas, mas agora já não os há.
> Existiam muitos problemas, mas agora (eles) já não existem.

Nota que o facto de *haver* ser impessoal não significa que orações impessoais não tenham sujeito, simplesmente esse sujeito é expletivo e não é um argumento do verbo. Sendo o português uma língua de sujeito nulo, este sujeito não tem geralmente expressão, contrariamente ao inglês (*it rains*). Se ocorrer, como pode acontecer em contextos enfáticos, será sempre *ele*:

> Ele havia muitos problemas.

Segundo a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (pág. 1194), este estatuto de *haver* como impessoal transitivo não era contudo consensual em fases anteriores da língua (e, discutivelmente, não o é também hoje em dia); por exemplo [escreveu Machado de Assis](http://www.sinergia-spe.net/editoraeletronica/autor/006/00601500_4.htm):

> ali haviam vários deputados que conversavam de política.

Há também dialetos em que *haver* concorda com o argumento (idem, pág. 133):

> O verbo *haver* tem, em alguns dialetos, um comportamento sintático diferente daquele que tem no português-padrão; esse comportamento consiste em apresentar flexão, na 3.ª pessoa do plural, no seu emprego como verbo existencial, como mostram os exemplos (57), registados em dialetos setentrionais e nos Açores [nota de rodapé: À exceção do presente do indicativo, a flexão da 3.ª pessoa do plural deste verbo ocorre, inclusivamente, na produção de falantes do dialeto-padrão (sobretudo em *haviam*, *houveram*, *haveriam*).]:
>
> (57) a. Aquelas canas grandes de pôr no feijão? Aqui não *hão*, não *hão*. (ALEPG, Cesar, Aveiro)
>        b. (A propósito dos caches das madressilvas): Eu já tive aqui. [...] *Hão* singelos e *hão* dobrados. (ALEPG, Cesar, Aveiro)
>        c. Mas também *hão* vacas arraianas. (ALEPG, Válega, Aveiro)
>        d. As forquilhas que *hão* por aqui... (ALEPG, Castelo de Neiva, Viana do Castelo)
>        e. *Hão* cabras que andem com ovelhas e *hão* cabras que andem só cabras. (ALEPG, Ponta Ruiva, Flores, Açores)
>        *[restantes exemplos omitidos]*

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Mesmo não desempenhando *muitos problemas* a função de sujeito, poderia ainda existir concordância verbal com o sintagma nominal se se tratasse de uma frase copulativa (como na construção impessoal *são dez horas*), o que não é o caso.</sub>

Comment: `haver é impessoal transitivo` - sempre? E quanto a `vocês hão-de me mostrar as fotos das vossas férias`? É impessoal transitivo também, e está mal usado? Ou...?

Comment: @ANeves Bem visto, qualifiquei a afirmação.

Comment: Resumindo em que é que ficamos?

Comment: @JorgeB. Que é impessoal transitivo no sentido de existir. Outros sentidos não são relevantes para esta pergunta.

Comment: Muito bem! Então já posso dizer, «hão aí umas coisas...» Se me repreenderem invoco em minha defesa o Machado de Assis.

Comment: Muito boa explicação.

Comment: @ANeves Queres dizer _impessoais transitivos_, não? São de facto raros em português. Existem outras construções impessoais como «vende-se casas» que talvez por isso sejam rejeitadas por alguns falantes. Vê a [penúltima citação desta resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1630/249).

Comment: (Isso, **im**pessoais. Vou re-adicionar o comentário, para corrigir.)

Comment: É-me extremamente difícil perceber isto sem recorrer ao meu conhecimento de línguas externas. Haverem verbos impessoais transitivos é *mesmo* confuso.

Answer (score 4):

Está correta porque *haver* pode ser um [*verbo impessoal*](http://www.normaculta.com.br/concordancia-verbal-com-verbos-impessoais/) quando tem sentido de "existir". Ser verbo impessoal significa que não tem sujeito, então não há nenhum sujeito para ter concordância verbal. "Os problemas" serve como objeto, não sujeito, da sua frase.

Comment: Mesmo assim, por exemplo, se substituíres o verbo haver por existir podes escrever "existem muitos problemas" ou não está correto?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, o verbo *existir* não é impessoal. Ser impessoal é uma qualidade gramatical de certos verbos.