# "para se descobrir" ou apenas "para descobrir"?

Tags: sintaxe, significado-em-contexto

Gostaria de saber se é correto utilizar a palavra ***se*** no contexto da frase abaixo:

> Foi iniciada uma luta para se descobrir de quem seria o prêmio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase com o ***se*** está perfeita; sem o ***se*** é gramatical mas o sentido é um pouco estranho. Vamos por partes.

### Com *se*

> Vai ser iniciada uma luta para **se descobrir** de quem é o prémio

Este ***se*** é o chamado *pronome indefinido* e representa um sujeito indeterminado:* refere-se a pessoas não especificadas que vão descobrir de quem é o prémio. É como dizer “vai ser iniciada uma luta para as pessoas descobrirem…” Encontramos o mesmo ***se*** nas frases seguintes:

> Come-**se** muito bem neste restaurante
>
> Ainda **se** morre de fome neste mundo

Também aqui o ***se*** se refere a pessoas não especificadas: as pessoas comem muito bem no tal restaurante; algumas pessoas ainda morrem de fome.

### Sem *se*

> Vai ser iniciada uma luta para **descobrir** de quem é o prémio

Aqui dizemos que a luta é que vai descobrir de quem é o prémio. Isto fica claro se compararmos com outras frases exatamente com a mesma estrutura:

> Vai ser contratado um detetive para descobrir quem fez isso. [O detetive vai descobrir.]
>
> Vai ser contratada uma ama para cuidar das crianças. [A ama vai cuidar.]
>
> Vai ser construída uma estrada para ligar a Vila Nova à Vila Velha. [A estrada vai ligar.]

A diferença é que é normalíssimo um detetive descobrir, uma ama cuidar ou uma estrada ligar; mas nós não dizemos habitualmente que uma luta descobre isto ou aquilo.

---

Nota:
* Existe uma análise alternativa da frase com ***se***, em que o “se descobrir” é voz passiva sintética. A frase continua igual e igualmente correta. Só muda a classificação gramatical dos vários elementos, e o sentido muda ligeirissimamente: é como dizer “para isso se descobrir” em que “isso” = “de quem é o prémio”, que é mais ou menos o mesmo que dizer “para ser descoberto de quem é o prémio”. Alguns—só alguns—gramáticos insistiriam até que esta é a única análise correta, pois não admitem a possibilidade do ***se***-sujeito indeterminado com verbos transitivos diretos como *descobrir*. Esses mesmo gramáticos rejeitam pela mesma razão a frase “vende-se casas”. Sobre este assunto ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/210/%C3%89-errado-dizer-vende-se-casas) e mais [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-voz-passiva-passive-voice-construction/1504#1504), em que se demonstra que eles não têm razão. Portanto as duas análises são possíveis. Eu prefiro a interpretação com ***se***-sujeito indeterminado em vez da passiva sintética porque me parece que quem ouve a frase pensa muito mais naturalmente “para pessoas não especificadas descobrirem de quem…” do que “para ser descoberto de quem…”

Comment: A interpretação dada ao sujeito de "descobrir" na frase sem "se" não é certamente "a luta". Sem mais, a frase parece-me de interpretação idêntica àquela com "se". Isto mudaria se a frase estivesse na voz activa: _Ele vai iniciar uma luta para descobrir de quem é o prémio_. Aqui, contrariamente à frase com "se", o sujeito de "descobrir" é "ele".

Comment: @Artefacto, a frase sem "se" não me soa bem. Como é que vês o "descobrir"? Como denotando a ação independentemente de quem a pratica? Tipo "é preciso coragem **para viver**"? Com a oração principal na voz ativa é muito claro, mas muitas dessas frases não me soam bem quando se passa a oração principal para voz passiva: "ele encheu a banheira para tomar banho" está perfeito, mas "a banheira foi enchida para tomar banho" não me entra na cabeça.