# Qual seria a análise morfossintática do termo "devem-se observar" na frase aprensentada?

Tags: verbos, concordância-verbal

Na frase:

"Na inserção ou supressão da pontuação nas estruturas restritivas ou explicativas, **devem-se observar**: (vários itens)"

A concordância verbal está correta? Qual seria a análise morfossintática do verbo e do pronome "se" de acordo com a linguagem formal?

Comment: Stafusa, sabes se esta pergunta já foi respondida algures? Não encontrei nenhuma, mas ela parece tão natural.

Comment: @Schilive Sim, eu diria que já foi: [É errado dizer "vende-se casas"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/210/2764).

Comment: @stafusa, "vende-se casas" não tem locução verbal como em "devem-se observar". Apresentei a dificuldade por esse motivo.

Comment: O que é locução verbal para você??

Answer (score 2):

A Moderna Gramática Portuguesa, de Evanildo Bechara, diz que podemos ver *dever se fazer X*/*dever ser feito X* de dois modos. Se interpretarmos *dever fazer-se X*/*deve ser feito X* como locução verbal, ela deve concordar com o sujeito, X; se interpretarmos *fazer X* como objeto de *dever-se*, o verbo *dever* estará na voz passiva, e, como *fazer X* é uma oração, o verbo estará no singular, semelhantemente a em *quer-se ver o Cristo Redentor* (= *é quisto ver o Cristo Redentor*), em que *ver o Cristo Redentor* é o sujeito de *querer-se*. Ambas são corretas e correntes.

---

> Devem-se matar os porcos a comer = Devem ser mortos os porcos a comer. (1º)
>
> Deve-se matar os porcos a comer = É devido matar os porcos a comer. (2º)

---

Comment: Votei positivo porque a explicação está muito bem apresentada, porém, vejo um pequeno problema ainda.
Reduzindo a frase, fica: "Na inserção ou supressão devem-se observar: (vários itens)". Então, pela sua explicação, seria uma locução verbal "devem observar" e o "se" seria uma partícula apassivadora. Se assim for, entendo que o objeto direto do verbo transitivo direto é transformado em sujeito passivo, e não o verbo "observar". 
Analisando dessa forma, se houvesse apenas um item, seria "deve-se observar" e, com mais de um item, "devem-se observar", pois o sujeito seria composto. Correto?

Comment: @zewill, a ser sincero, eu pus a carroça na frente dos bois. Pelo que entendi duma pesquisa, há duas maneiras de analisar dever-se fazer. Uma é sendo dever-se fazer*/*dever ser feito uma locução verbal na voz passiva. A outra é ver fazer-se*/*ser feito como objeto de dever. Vou mudar a resposta. Obrigado por comentar.

Comment: então o seu segundo exemplo está gramaticalmente correto? Ou o verbo deve concordar com o sujeito?

Comment: @zewill, ambos os exemplos estão corretos. No primeiro exemplo, vê-se *devem-se matar* como uma locução verbal; no segundo, vê-se *matar os porcos* como objeto de *dever*, então, *dever* tem sujeito indefinido.

Comment: Quase entendi :) Entendi que, no segundo caso, seria um sujeito oracional, devendo o verbo estar na forma impessoal, ficando na 3ª pessoa do singular. Mas, ao meu ver, "dever matar" seria um só processo verbal, o que caracteriza uma locução verbal. Ou uma locução verbal pode ser desmembrada dessa forma sempre? Porque nesse caso o verbo auxiliar está em um termo da oração (verbo) e o verbo principal seria outro termo (sujeito). Em que situações isso pode acontecer?

Comment: Novamente, errei. Eu devia parar de fazer estas coisas à noite. O verbo *dever* em *deve-se matar os porcos* está na voz passiva, assim como **quer**-se comprar casas» (= «é quisto comprar casas»), em que *comprar casas* é sujeito passivo. Isto é, «deve-se matar os porcos a comer» é «é devido matar os porcos a comer», e «devem-se matar os porcos a comer» é «devem ser mortos os porcos a comer».

Comment: Schilive e @zewill, eu sou capaz de estar já a chover no molhado, mas a frase da pergunta só pode ser passiva sintética com a locução verbal *devem-se observar* (com subida do clítico) e o sujeito paciente são os vários itens (correspondente à passiva analítica *os itens devem ser observados* é à voz ativa *devemos/devo/etc. observar os itens). Para ser o objeto ser *observar os itens*, que e singular, teria de ser *deve-se [observar os itens]* que pode ser interpretado como passiva sintética ou voz ativa com sujeito indeterminado *se*.

Answer (score 0):

A concordância é feita por ser um verbo auxiliar e um principal. Como o verbo principal não é impessoal ele assume a forma de infinitivo e o verbo auxiliar concorda com o sujeito. A concordância não é baseada na partícula (se).